# Input field style attribute in javascript works fine in chrome and not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

In my page for file upload field i set the attibute style in javascript  as below

```
choicefile.setAttribute("style", "width: 86px;
                                  position: absolute;
                                  margin-left: 83px;  //This pixels shows the upload field in a correct place
                                  margin-top: 90px;  // This pixels shows the upload field in a correct place
                                  z-index: 1;
                                  opacity: 0;");
```

But in Firefox it shows the file upload in a wrong place. In firefox if we change the two attributes as

```
choicefile.setAttribute("style", "width: 86px;
                                  position: absolute;
                                  margin-left: 35px;  //In Firefox it is the correct pixels
                                  margin-top: 150px;  //In Firefox it is the correct pixels
                                  z-index: 1;
                                  opacity: 0;");
```

How can i solve this problem. Anybody can help for this problem. Thanks in advance

My URL is

http://mytest.php?id=2&mview=69

After click the addnewentry the file uploader displayed in correct place but in firefox it is displayed in wrong place.

```
<form name="choiceadd" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validationaddchoice();">
<span id="addnewcontain">
</span>
<input type="hidden" name="choicecount" value="0" />
<div class="four" style='margin-top:40px;'>
<input type="button" value="Add New Entry" onclick="addnewchoice(document.forms['choiceadd']['choicecount'].value)" >
</div>
<div class="five">
<input type="submit" name="choiceaddsubmit" class="choiceaddsubmit" />
</div>
</form>
```

The above is the form in main page. When click this button the function addchoice is called and it includes the choicefile attribute style mentioned above

The function is

```
function addnewchoice(val)
{choicefile.setAttribute("style", "width: 86px; position: absolute; margin-left: 83px; margin-top: 90px; z-index: 1; opacity: 0;");
}
```

Comment: This is the antithesis of a SSCCE. Where is the `addnewentry` button? Is it even a button?

Comment: Clarification for @Asad's comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (I had to google it, so more people might've)

Comment: Added the form coding that contains the addnewentry button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of setting style like this, you can do it like the one below for fully cross browser compatibility.Assign each style property like the one below

instead of setting style

```
function addnewchoice(val)
{   
   choicefile.setAttribute("style", "width: 86px; position: absolute; margin-left: 83px; margin-top: 90px; z-index: 1; opacity: 0;");
}
```

you can set it like this for cross browser compatibility

```
function addnewchoice(val)
    choicefile.style.width="86px";
    choicefile.style.position="absolute";
    ... so on..
}
```

Comment: She asks for giving style attribute within the javascript function with browser compatability code

Answer (score 1):

The perfect answer for this question is

```
<style>
   @-moz-document url-prefix() {
                       .testview{
                      width: 86px;
                      position: absolute;
                      margin-left: 35px;
                      margin-top: 90px;
                      z-index: 1;
                      opacity: 0;
                    }
                 }
</style>
```

If the browser is mozilla firefox then the above style with the corresponding attribute is applied to the page. If the browser is chrome means the default style will apply